# What is the connection pattern for multi-pole push button switches like this one?

Tags: switches, button

[image]
[image]
[image]

It does not appear to be one of the two obvious choices - one side common or button down connects terminals across from each other.

Used on an HVAC unit.

It is busted so I can not probe it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: What was on the labels next to each button?

Comment: @stark Updated OP with photo of the faceplate. Thanks!

Comment: PTAC controls should go to Heater (Heat), Compressor (Cool), High speed fan (High), Low speed fan (Low) or neither (Auto/Standby).  You might be able to get a diagram based on the Manufacturer and Model.

Comment: that is a custom made device .... the interconnection depends on the manufacturer's requirement  ...... the pictures are not useful for anything other than showing what you are talking about

Comment: look for a wiring diagram sheet inside the hvac device

Comment: @jsotola Inside is only an empty envelope that says "Wiring Diagram - DO NOT DISCARD" :)

Comment: @stark Agreed, but it is unclear how the connections are made when the buttons are pressed without a wiring diagram. I have searched (it is a `Single WM-120`) but so far not found one. Thanks!

Comment: is there anything on the underside of the switch? ...... is the brand name "Single"? .... any other labels on the unit?